# sorting numbers in order - bubble sort - C++

Tags: c++, sorting, numbers

there i need to do a program that will generate random numbers and sort them.
The program need to generate them from the srand () function to initialize the random number series. The program should display the list in ascending order or descending order all three need to be side-by-side.

There is a problem in my code with sorting numbers in ascending order and waning.

There's my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
int n,j=0;
int temp;
int compt=2;
int compt2=2;
int tab [50];
int random = 0;

cout<< "\n Bonjour!";
do
{
    cout<< "\n\n Entrer la longeur de liste que vous desirez (5 a 50) : ";
    cin>> n;

    if(5>n || n>50)
    {
        cout<< "\n ``ERREUR``";
    }
}while (5>n || n>50);

srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
cout<<"\n ";
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    random = (rand()%n+1);
    tab [j] = random;
    cout<<tab[j]<<" ";
}
while(compt>1)
{
    compt=0;
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(tab[j]>tab[j+1])
            {
                temp = tab[j];
                tab[j] = tab [j+1];
                tab [j+1] = temp;
                compt+=1;   
            }
        }
}
cout<<"\n apres tri croissant"<<endl;
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
    cout<<tab[j-1]<<" ";

}
cout<<"\n apres tri deroissant"<<endl;
for(j=(n-1);j>=0;j--)
{
    cout<<tab[j-1]<<" ";

}
cout<<"test";



}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look at using std::algorithms to handle sorting.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
    if(tab[j]>tab[j+1])
```

you have an error. Number `n` is size of your array, to maximum array index is `n-1`. In this code, on last comparison, you are comparing `tab[n-1]` with `tab[n]`.

Try chaning it to:

```
for (j=0;j<(n-1);j++)
    {
    if(tab[j]>tab[j+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
while(compt>1){
    compt=0;
    int aux = tab[0]; //We create an auxiliar variable with 1st value in array
    for (j=1;j<n;j++){
        if(aux>tab[j]){ //We sort it
            temp = aux;
            aux = tab [j];
            tab [j] = temp;
            compt++;   //As you're adding +1 each time, you can change compt += 1 for compt++ (does the same)
        }
    }
}
```

This code was

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    cout<<tab[j-1]<<" ";
}
```

If I'm not wrong 'cause I can't test it by now, it should be: 'cause it would be printing at 1st place tab[0-1] i.e (tab[-1]) that we all know, it doesn't exists.

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    cout<<tab[j]<<" ";
}
```

That should work